# perl script working in vmware server but fails in vmware ESXi

Tags: perl

This problem is really puzzling to me: I have the following script working on vmware server 2.0:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
# server (transmitter)
use strict;
use IO::Socket::Multicast6;
use IO::Interface;
use constant GROUP => "235.1.1.2";
use constant PORT  => "3000";
my $sock = IO::Socket::Multicast6->new(
                   Proto=>"udp",
                   Domain=>AF_INET,
                   PeerAddr=>GROUP,
                   PeerPort=>PORT);
$sock->mcast_if("eth1");
$sock->mcast_ttl(10);
while (1) {
   my $message = localtime();
   $sock->send($message) || die "Could not  send: $!";
} continue {
   sleep 4;
}
```

It works great on vmware server. I have cloned this VM to an EXSi server but running the same exact copy of the virtual machine running the script, and I get the following error:

**Can't call method "mcast_if" on an undefined value**

Im really puzzled by this as I am not sure what the problem could be. 
there is really nothing different except for the CPU running on both machines, but I don't see how something so low level can be causing an issue but I could be wrong. perl -d wasn't very helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's failing to create the socket, use some error checking to try to find out why. Eg:

```
my $sock = IO::Socket::Multicast6->new(
   Proto=>"udp",
   Domain=>AF_INET,
   PeerAddr=>GROUP,
   PeerPort=>PORT)
   or die "Socket failed: $!";
```

Comment: yep it totally helped and I am a little embarrassed. This VM guys have a script that resets the routes to not include a default GW in production since is a contained environment. Since this VM doesn't have a route for the mcast traffic it fails to create the socket. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

The `new()` constructor is failing, but not raising an exception. I don’t know its API: is there some way to get it to tell you why?

Otherwise you might try errno (that is, `$!`).